# Predicate with DapperExtensions

Tags: c#, dapper

Im trying to make a generic Find method with DapperExtensions

This is my method

```
 public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cn = GetCn())
        {
            cn.Open();

            var predicate = Predicates.Field<T>(expression, Operator.Eq, true);
            return cn.GetList<T>(predicate);
        }
    }
```

But i get `System.NullReferenceException` on this row  `var predicate = Predicates.Field<T>(expression, Operator.Eq, true);`

This is from the DapperExtensions help documentation
But I try convert this to a Generic method.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    var predicate = Predicates.Field<Person>(f => f.Active, Operator.Eq, true);
    IEnumerable<Person> list = cn.GetList<Person>(predicate);
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the sort of expression you are passing in? Because notably the example is `Func<T,bool>`, where-as yours is `Func<T,object>` - that is the most *obvious* difference I can see...

Comment: This is what i passing in Find(p => p.MarketId == marketId);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't repro'd, but it *looks* like the issue is, in part, that you are making the expression more complex than the example. As a suggestion, try:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression,
                                   TValue value)
{
    using (IDbConnection cn = GetCn())
    {
        cn.Open();

        var predicate = Predicates.Field<T>(expression, Operator.Eq, value);
        return cn.GetList<T>(predicate);
    }
}
```

and:

```
var data = Find(p => p.MarketId, marketId);
```

This is completely untested, based just on your comments and the example.

If your code-base doesn't make that practical, then I would suggest just *try* it with the above to see if that *works*, because there are ways of pulling apart an expression to extract those pieces. But it isn't worth giving an example of that until we know whether the above works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. On this row var predicate = Predicates.Field<T>(expression, Operator.Eq, value); i got "The best overloaded method match for DapperExtensions.Predicates.Field<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, object>>, DapperExtensions.Operator, object, bool) has som invalid arguments.

Comment: I changed TValue to Object, now its running perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: @MarcGravell nice answer - how would one implement this so that we can call Find thus: `var matchingPersons = conn.Find<Person>(p => p.MarketId == marketId);`. I would like to pull apart the expression so that I can build the predicate that GetList<T>() requires: the parameter (`p.MarketId`), the operator (`Operator.Eq, Operator.Gt, Operator.Lt ...`), and the value (`marketId`). Thanks.

Comment: @SameerSingh how have you got on with that? you should find the lambda.Body is an EqualsExpression, with a "left" MemberExpression that takes the member "MarketId" of the ParameterExpression, and the right is probably a MemberExpression (marketId) on a ConstantExpression that is the captured variable scope instance. It *should* therefore unroll pretty easily

Comment: @MarcGravell your suggestion makes sense (except I tried using a BinaryExpression), but no luck. :( I have posted another question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154783/pulling-apart-expressionfunct-object). Regarding the comment made by @anpe we have to use `Expression<Func<T, object>` because `Predicates.Field<T>` expects that and not `Expression<Func<T, TValue>`