# Pulling Apart Expression<Func<T, object>>

Tags: c#, extension-methods, dapper

I am busy creating wrapper extension methods on top of [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and [DapperExtensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions). At the moment I am trying to add filtering to the `GetList<T>` extension method, similar to LINQ's `Where<T>` extension method. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585212/predicate-with-dapperextensions) but it seems I cannot implement what [Marc Gravell suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585212/predicate-with-dapperextensions#comment-21308084) because there isn't a type `EqualsExpression` in .NET 4.5. Here is some demo code to help with the explanation of my problem:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using DapperExtensions;

namespace Dapper.Extensions.Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DapperDbContext"].ConnectionString;
        public static IDbConnection Connection { get { return new SqlConnection(ConnectionString); } }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int marketId = 2;
            var matchingPeople = Connection.Get<Person>(p => p.MarketId, marketId); // This works

            // Below is a LambdaExpression. expression.Body is, bizarrely, a UnaryExpression with a Convert
            //var matchingPeople = Connection.Get<Person>(p => p.MarketId == marketId); // Does not work

            foreach (var person in matchingPeople)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(person);
            }

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class SqlConnectionExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(this IDbConnection connection, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, object value = null) where T : class
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                connection.Open();

                // I want to be able to pass in: t => t.Id == id then:
                // Expression<Func<T, object>> expressionOnLeftOfFilterClause = t => t.Id;
                // string operator = "==";
                // object valueFromLambda = id;
                // and call Predicates.Field(expressionOnLeftOfFilterClause, Operator.Eq, valueFromLambda)

                var predicate = Predicates.Field(expression, Operator.Eq, value);
                var entities = connection.GetList<T>(predicate, commandTimeout: 30);
                connection.Close();
                return entities;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public int MarketId { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}: {1}, {2} - MarketId: {3}", Id, Surname, FirstName, MarketId);
        }
    }
}
```

Paying particular attention to my `Get<T>` extension method: when I pass in either `p => p.MarketId` or `p => p.MarketId == marketId`, `expression.Body` is of type `UnaryExpression`. For the latter, `expression.Body` actually contains `{Convert((p.MarketId == 2))}`.

Attempting

```cs
var binaryExpression = expression as BinaryExpression;
```

returns `null`, which is unfortunate because there are `Left` and `Right` properties which I could have found useful.

So, does anyone know how to achieve what I want? Further down the line I would like to be able to pick the `Operator` enum based on the lambda expression passed in. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be that the `Operand` property of the `UnaryExpression` will be the `BinaryExpression` you're looking for.

Comment: @Iridium I think you're right; through debugging I can see that the `Operand` of `expression.Body` is of type `LogicalBinaryExpression` but how do I access `expression.Body.Operand` in-code? Intellisense cannot resolve that?

Comment: @Iridium is absolutely right, just tried it now: `            BinaryExpression binary = (expr.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as BinaryExpression;` yields the much desired `BinaryExpression`. @Jon Skeet explained to you perfectly why the conversion appears (value types being boxed to `object`)... Beware of even more complex expression trees that you yourself might send yourself. You cannot do an expression tree parser that has a high spectrum of possibilities on the user programmer side and make very big assumptions on the library writer side...

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but before starting to write libraries (not to mention LINQ parsers) I suggest you try to gain a better understanding of basic OOP. An expression tree is a subset of an "Abstract Syntax Tree". That means that each node is of an abstract type (syntactically) which at runtime might end up to be a more concrete type which in turn contains one ore more abstract instances (which at runtime end up to be something). This abstract / concrete tango dance is what makes your IDE's Intellisense not to work. You must assume things, test their validity and act accordingly by subcasting

Comment: @Eduard I am perfectly aware of OOP principles. I know about abstract and concrete types and I am also aware that I could pass in a more complex lambda expression which I will need to parse. Admittedly I have not spent much time constructing expression trees in-code which is why I posted the question in the first place. And yes I have skimmed MSDN for pointers.

Comment: Then please note these simple facts: 1) `UnaryExpression` has a property called `Operand` of type `Expression`. 2)`BinaryExpression` extends `Expression`. 3) that wouldn't be enough if logically speaking the possibility of applying any unary operation on the result of a binary operation **would not be a clear reality**. You did ask @Iridium why doesn't Visual Studio intelli-help you with the auto-complete dropdown. That was a beacon that made me think you weren't aware of these things. Now that I know you actually are, (without any shadow of sarcasm) I must apologize. I made a wrong assumption

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured out how to achieve what I want.

**In summary:**

1. I need an extension method which wraps DapperExtension's `GetList<T>` extension method.
2. The latter may take in a predicate of type `IFieldPredicate` which I can use to add a filter to the SQL query to be executed. I can achieve this by using `Predicates.Field<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, Operator op, object value)`.
3. The problem lies in transforming a simple lambda expression `t => t.Id == id` into parameters for `Predicates.Field<T>`. So, conceptually, I need to pull apart the lambda expression into three parts: `t => t.Id`, `Operator.Eq`, and `id`.

With help from @Iridium, @Eduard and @Jon, my final solution is:

```cs
public static class SqlConnectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(this IDbConnection connection, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression) where T : class
    {
        using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();

            var binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)((UnaryExpression) expression.Body).Operand;

            var left = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(binaryExpression.Left, typeof(object)), expression.Parameters[0]);
            var right = binaryExpression.Right.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(binaryExpression.Right);
            var theOperator = DetermineOperator(binaryExpression);

            var predicate = Predicates.Field(left, theOperator, right);
            var entities = connection.GetList<T>(predicate, commandTimeout: 30);

            connection.Close();
            return entities;
        }
    }

    private static Operator DetermineOperator(Expression binaryExpression)
    {
        switch (binaryExpression.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Equal:
                return Operator.Eq;
            case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
                return Operator.Gt;
            case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                return Operator.Ge;
            case ExpressionType.LessThan:
                return Operator.Lt;
            case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
                return Operator.Le;
            default:
                return Operator.Eq;
        }
    }
}
```

I can now do this:

```cs
var matchingPeople = Connection.Get<Person>(p => p.MarketId == marketId);
```

I know how brittle this is - it will break if I pass in anything more complex, or even something that looks to be equivalent, like `var matchingPeople = Connection.Get<Person>(p => p.MarketId.Equals(marketId));`. It does solve 90% of my cases though so I am content to leave it as-is.

Comment: Thanks for this solution.

MYSQL: There was 1 error that i fixed, Value should be replaced with Member: var right = binaryExpression.Right.GetType().GetProperty("Member").GetValue(binaryExpression.Right);

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
Expression<Func<T, object>> expression
```

Your function has to return `object`. The type of `p.MarketId == marketId` is `bool`. It therefore needs to be boxed to `object`, hence the `Convert`.

If the expression is always meant to be a predicate, you should change it to:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression
```

At that point, I'd expect you to see the appropriate binary expression. On the other hand, that then won't work for `p => p.MarketId`...

To be honest, it's not really clear what the parameters are meant to mean. It feels like maybe you want two methods - one for a *single* parameter which is a predicate, and one for *two* parameters: a projection and a target value.

Comment: Jon, yes that's true; however, I need to pass `Expression<Func<T, object>>` into Predicates.Field<T>. Is there an elegant way to convert between the two?

Comment: That's from the DapperExtensions library, [Predicates.cs](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/blob/master/DapperExtensions/Predicates.cs)

Comment: @SameerSingh: Okay... so why would you expect `Get(p => p.MarketId == marketId)` to work at all? That would effectively be saying `.Where(p => (p.MarketId == marketId) == null)` given your value defaulting... that doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: Well I made the `value` parameter optional so that I can switch between `var matchingPeople = Connection.Get<Person>(p => p.MarketId, marketId);`and `var matchingPeople = Connection.Get<Person>(p => p.MarketId == marketId);`. I will be removing that parameter once I get the latter working (by parsing `p => p.MarketId == marketId` into its constituent parts).

Comment: @SameerSingh: As I suggested in my answer, it makes little sense to have a single method when the two different invocation forms mean very different things. Split it out into two different methods *now*, and get each working individually.