# Grouping Lambda Expressions by Operators and Using Them With DapperExtensions' PredicateGroups

Tags: c#, extension-methods, dapper

Pursuant to my previous question: [`Pulling Apart Expression<Func<T, object>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154783/pulling-apart-expressionfunct-object) - I am trying to make it a bit more advanced. Currently, I can do this:

```cs
var matchingPeople = Connection.Get<Person>(p => p.MarketId == marketId);
```

which will be converted into a [DapperExtensions `FieldPredicate`](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Predicates):

```cs
// Assume I've successfully parsed p => p.MarketId == marketId into its constituent parts:
// left = p => p.MarketId, theOperator = Operator.Eq, right = marketId
Predicates.Field(left, theOperator, right);
```

I now want to be able to do this:

```cs
var matchingPeople = Connection.Get<Person>(p => p.MarketId == marketId && p.FirstName == "John" || p.FirstName == "Jack");
```

and generate SQL that looks something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @MarketId INT = 3
DECLARE @FirstName01 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'John'
DECLARE @FirstName02 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Jack'

SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE MarketId = @MarketId AND (FirstName = @FirstName01 OR FirstName = @FirstName02)
```

by using [DapperExtensions `Compound Predicate Groups`](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Predicates):

```cs
// ** This is the code I am trying to dynamically create based on the lambda that is passed in **

var predicateGroupAnd = new PredicateGroup {Operator = GroupOperator.And, Predicates = new List<IPredicate>()};
// I already have the code to determine: left = p => p.MarketId, theOperator = Operator.Eq, right = marketId
predicateGroupAnd.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field(left, Operator.Eq, right));

var predicateGroupOr = new PredicateGroup {Operator = GroupOperator.Or, Predicates = new List<IPredicate>()};
// I already have the code to determine: left = p => p.FirstName, theOperator = Operator.Eq, right = "John"
predicateGroupAnd.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field(left, Operator.Eq, right));
// I already have the code to determine: left = p => p.FirstName, theOperator = Operator.Eq, right = "Jack"
predicateGroupOr.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field(left, Operator.Eq, right));

var predicateGroupAll = new PredicateGroup // This is what will be passed to DapperExtensions' GetList<T> method
    {
        Operator = GroupOperator.And, // How do I set this correctly?
        Predicates = new List<IPredicate> {predicateGroupAnd, predicateGroupOr}
    };
```

My problem seems to be around the way expression trees are parsed. Assume we have the lambda expression:

```cs
p => p.MarketId == marketId && p.FirstName == "John" || p.FirstName == "Jack"
```

I can cast this to a `BinaryExpression`. If I use `BinaryExpression.Left`, I get

```cs
p.MarketId == marketId && p.FirstName == "John"
```

and `BinaryExpression.Right` yields:

```cs
p.FirstName == "Jack"
```

Also, the `NodeType` of the overall `BinaryExpression` seems to be set to the last conditional operator of the lambda, i.e. [`ExpressionType.OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179.aspx)

I feel like I need to use recursion and traverse the lambda expression from right to left, but I haven't been able to create the compound group predicates that I want. Specifically, how do I group the `AND` lambdas together, and the `OR` lambdas together? Thanks!

Comment: Note that `&&` has a higher operator precedence than `||`, which is why it's created the expression tree that it has. Use brackets around the || if you want it the other way around (as your SQL indicates).

Comment: This would also probably be useful: http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Your example lambda,

```
p => p.MarketId == marketId && p.FirstName == "John" || p.FirstName == "Jack"
```

is the equivilent of

```
p => (p.MarketId == marketId && p.FirstName == "John") || p.FirstName == "Jack"
```

because `&&` has a higher precendence than `||`.

Because of this you'll get a tree with the `&&` at the "bottom", (as it needs to be calculated first) then the `||` on top:

```
                         ||
                        /  \
                       &&  Firstname == "Jack"
                      /  \
p.MarketId == marketId    p.FirstName == "John"
```

Once you understand operator precedence the above makes sense. If you want an alternative you can just use brackets to force the `||` to be evaluated first (making it end up at the bottom of the expression tree).

```
p => p.MarketId == marketId && (p.FirstName == "John" || p.FirstName == "Jack")
```

---

Your general problem is that you're approaching this slightly wrong. Currently you are trying to create 2 groups, one for ORs and one for ANDs. This might work in this case, but not in the general one, for example, what would you do for this: `(a && b) || (c && d)`?

I think what should happen is that each and and each or should translate into its own predicate group. See the "Multiple Compound Predicates (Predicate Group)" section of your linked article. You'd simply replace BinaryExpression with a predicate group.

In your example you have (a && b) || c with the || at the top. What you want to end up with is each time you have an operator you want to create a predicate group, with the left and right as the list of expressions.
In your logic to convert a binaryexpression to a predicate group you would first use that same function to convert the left and the right into a predicate group

i.e. your code sees the ||.
it creates a predicate group ready to add the expressions to its list
it chooses left first (doesn't matter).
ok, left is another binary expression, so it calls itself to get a predicategroup that your target library understands
so that recursion is working on only a && b. It chooses left first, sees a simple predicate, a which means it can simply add it to the predicate group, it does the same for the right
then we're back up to the original call to the function which now has a predicate group with the lower expression on the left converted to a different predicate group and added.
it goes down the right now, which is simple an individual predicate and so it can add it to its list.

> Okay, so if I had something crazy like: `a && b || c || d && e`

Ok, taking into account higher precedence we get the following:
`((a && b) || c) || (d && e)`
note that i'm not 100% sure about either the bracket would put c with the first && or the last, but it doesn't matter, the logic is the same
When visualising the tree, start with the innermost brackets. They are the "leaves"
then work outwards, using the brackets to work up the tree, finally arriving at the root node, which in our case is the || to the right of c:

```
       ||
     /    \
    ||     &&
   /  \   /  \
  &&   c d   e
 /  \
a    b
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the lambda being passed in, so I cannot bracket the lambda to change the way it is evaluated as you have shown. Regardless of the operator precedence, I want to be able to parse the lambda from right to left in a recursive manner. `BinaryExpression.Right` gives me the right-most expression, and I also get the operator to its left so I know its grouping (`AND` or `OR`). When I parse the *next* right-most lambda, I want to place it in the group that the previous lambda belongs to.

Comment: So I want to parse the right-most lambdas two at a time with the joining conditional operator. When I get to the point of the left-most lambda, I want to look at its conditional operator to its right and place it in the appropriate group. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow the general case here. I understand that in this example you want to group the John/Jack tests with the OR operator but I don't understand the general problem you want to solve, are there different rules of operator precedence in your target language for example? Remember that the lambda expression isn't written down, it's a tree structure (as in my answer here). I think what you want is to produce one where `&&` is at the top and Jack and John are on the right with the `||`, but I don't know why you want that, or what else you'd want with different inputs.

Comment: Could you look at the tree structure in my answer and know what output you want, knowing nothing of how the expression is written in the first place? (because the code doesn't see how it's written)

Comment: For the moment, assume there is no operator precedence. `&&` has the same precedence as `||`. The issue is now how to parse the overall lambda two expressions at a time, from right to left (as mentioned before, `BinaryExpression.Right` gives me the right-most expression, while `BinaryExpression.NodeType` gives me the operator to its left). Once that has been solved, we can consider operator precedence.

Comment: My question then is, why do you want to parse it from right to left? It looks like you're trying to create 2 predicate groups, one for the ands and one for the ors to which should be logically equivilent. While that might work in your example case it won't in the general case. Consider `(a && b) || (c && d)` What would you do then? I think what should happen is that each `and` and each `or` should translate into its own predicate group. See the "Multiple Compound Predicates (Predicate Group)" section of your linked article. You'd simply replace BinaryExpression with a predicate group.

Comment: Under the left or right of that predicate group you might have another predicate group.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28652/discussion-between-sameer-singh-and-george-duckett)

Comment: For a really good understanding, take a look at these blog posts: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx

Comment: I notice I got a -1, anything I can do to improve this post?

Comment: Hi, yes I meant to comment on this but then my PC blue-screened. :( Anyway - although your answer helped me to progress towards an answer to my problem initially (in terms of understanding operator precedence), it fell apart once I wrote the recursion code to build the predicate groups. It seems BinaryExpression.Left and BinaryExpression.Right don't honour the rules you set out and I have spent hours trying to make it so with no luck. So ... your answer only tangentially solves the original problem.

Comment: If you could edit your question with an example that doesn't follow the rules I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: I will do so a bit later - busy with a different project at the moment